# How to adjust div height from auto to content height first and then fill it with content, not the other way around?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to transition the `#two` element from `height: auto` to its contents height.

Based on [this](http://n12v.com/css-transition-to-from-auto/), I have came up with the below code.

It works, but there is an unpleasant side-effect: the content will be created first and only then parent div will start to adapt its width.

How can I correct that? I am also open to pure CSS, non-JS solutions.

```js
            let fill_button = document.getElementById('fill')
            let div_to_fill = document.getElementById('two')
            
            fill.addEventListener('click', function() {
                fill_parent_with_some_content(div_to_fill)
            })
            
            function fill_parent_with_some_content(parent) {
                
                let content_height = '200px'
                
                // create new element
                let content = document.createElement('div')
                content.style.margin = '0'
                content.style.height = content_height
                content.style.width ='300px'
                content.style.background = 'orange'

                // height transition from auto
                parent.style.height = getComputedStyle(parent).height
                parent.style.transition = 'height 2s ease-in-out'
                parent.offsetHeight // force repaint
                parent.style.height = content_height
                
                parent.appendChild(content)   
            }
```

```css
#one, #two, #three {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
#one, #three {
  height: 100px;
}
#two {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
            <style>
                
                    
            </style>
        <body>
            <button id="fill">Fill second div with some content</button>
            <div id="one"></div>
            <div id="two"></div>
            <div id="three"></div>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: `overflow:hidden` ?

Comment: @Temani Afif: Yes, setting this on parent element worked.